# pyqt5でmatplotlibを使ってグラフを書きたいが、一つのキャンパスに複数のグラフを書けない

Tags: python, pyqt5

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5でmatplotlibを使ってグラフを書きたいです。しかし、一つのキャンパス内に複数のグラフを書くことができません。イメージとしてはplotボタンを押した時にsin関数とcos関数の二つが一つのグラフ内に重なって表示されるの様に、下のコードに書いたつもりです。しかし、後から書いたcos関数のみが表示されてしまいます。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random
import numpy as np


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("グラフ")
        self.setGeometry(300,300,500,500)

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.move(0,0)


        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        #self.toolbar.hide()

        # Just some button 
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot',self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        btnlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        qw = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        qw.setLayout(btnlayout)
        layout.addWidget(qw)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot(self):
        x1=np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
        y1=np.sin(x1)
        self.axes.plot(x1,y1,c="r",label="sin")
        self.axes.legend(loc="best")
        self.canvas.draw()

        x2=np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
        y2=np.cos(x2)
        self.axes.plot(x2,y2,c="b",label="cos")
        self.axes.legend(loc="best")
        self.canvas.draw()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Window()
    main.setWindowTitle('Simple QTpy and MatplotLib example with Zoom/Pan')
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.axes.hold(False)
```

を消したらできました。